# ActiveMQ 5.15 and GlassFish5

Tags: glassfish, activemq-classic

I am trying to frend active mq and glass fish server. I copied jars from activemq into libs of glassfish. [jars][1]

Also I made configuration according this article 
[GlassFish  and ActiveMQ][1]

But on the step Run the admin Console I stuck. I am reciving exception

```
   StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
    java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40)
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:148)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:342)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.lookup(RegistryContext.java:132)
        at com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.lookup(GenericURLContext.java:205)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:417)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServerJNDI(RMIConnector.java:1955)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.findRMIServer(RMIConnector.java:1922)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:287)
        at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:270)
        at org.apache.activemq.web.RemoteJMXBrokerFacade.createConnection(RemoteJMXBrokerFacade.java:133)
        at org.apache.activemq.web.RemoteJMXBrokerFacade.getMBeanServerConnection(RemoteJMXBrokerFacade.java:103)
        at org.apache.activemq.web.RemoteJMXBrokerFacade.getBrokerAdmin(RemoteJMXBrokerFacade.java:78)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:362)
        at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:188)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:139)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:203)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstDynamicExpression.getValue(AstDynamicExpression.java:63)
        at com.sun.el.parser.AstCompositeExpression.getValue(AstCompositeExpression.java:68)
        at com.sun.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:226)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.evaluateExpression(PageContextImpl.java:1016)
        at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_c_out_0(index_jsp.java:394)
        at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:91)
        at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:111)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:411)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:473)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:377)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:338)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.activemq.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:45)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.activemq.web.filter.ApplicationContextFilter.doFilter(ApplicationContextFilter.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:250)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:256)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
        at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
        at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
        at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
```

Ping of connection pull is successful
    Port 8080 is not ocupied by othe application. Tryed to change to 9999 - didn't help.

What can be wrong in the configuration?

Comment: https://javadude.wordpress.com/2011/07/21/glassfish-v3-1-running-embedded-activemq-for-jms-part-1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in the BrokerXmlConfig. I don't know the reason, but sometimes glassfish displayes If it will be message from GlassFish server Invalid property syntax, "=" in value: BrokerXmlConfig=broker:(vm://default\&broker.persistent=false) just delete = and save settings. I just delete = and continued to configure activemq. After I againe put = and saved changes and application has worked.